# Is there any MongoDB driver that supports wire compression?

Tags: java, mongodb, compression

MongoDB can be run with this option: `--networkMessageCompressors=snappy`. According to documentation, this compresses network exchanges between mongod, mongos and the mongo shell.

I would like to compress traffic between a Java application and a mongod, but none of the Java drivers do offer this option.

Have any of you tried one of the following paths ?

- patch the Java driver so that it supports compression (it would be my preferred solution of course but I could use some advice on directions to follow)
- wrap another driver that supports compression to expose it to Java apps (but I don't know if any other driver supports this feature)

Of course, any other way that could help me compress that payload would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've noted, the [network compression feature](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.compression.compressors) added in MongoDB 3.4 is currently only supported for intra-cluster communication between members of a replica set or sharded cluster (`mongod` or `mongos`) as well as the `mongo` shell. As of the MongoDB 3.4 release there are no official drivers that support network compression.

There's a relevant feature request you can watch/upvote in the MongoDB issue tracker for client/driver support: [SERVER-25620: Compression of wire protocol for Clients](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-25620). This feature request also has a comment providing some [context on the lack of client support](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-25620?focusedCommentId=1358580&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-1358580):

> For some background, the decision to implement wire protocol compression came very late in the MongoDB 3.4 development cycle. We agree that it would be good for clients to be able to take advantage of the feature, but to do so for MongoDB 3.4 would have required that all official MongoDB drivers add support as well, and that just didn't seem realistic given the timeline. Also, by keeping wire protocol compression cluster-internal only, it will give us some ability to refine the feature before we open it up to clients and are effectively locked in to a design. We will be evaluating whether to extend support for compression to clients during MongoDB 3.6 development.

You could consider implementing a patch for the Java driver if there is a significant win for your use case, however there are likely changes coming during the 3.6 development cycle and it may be more prudent to wait for official driver support.

> Of course, any other way that could help me compress that payload would be highly appreciated.

Instead of modifying the driver, you could take advantage of network compression using a VPN or TLS/SSL compression. VPN compression is probably the more recommendable approach.

TLS/SSL compression depends on a number of factors including whether your TLS/SSL libraries are built with compression enabled or disabled by default. A number of O/S distributions and languages/drivers have disabled TLS/SSL compression due to high profile security exploits like [CRIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRIME). Although MongoDB theoretically isn't vulnerable to the CRIME attack (which is against authenticated web sessions), many users consider TLS compression a security concern.